# Error SHARED_VIEW_USER_LACKS_PERMISSION on DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest

Tags: php, docusignapi

My scenario would be this flow in my application: Register > Sign Document > Return to Finish Page.
The user register on my application and he need to sign a document to finish his registration. He is not a DocuSign user. At the moment all my tests are at the Sandbox environment.

The envelope creation works great. If I don't use the client_user_id it sends the email for signing. But I need to use the client_user_id to use the embedded signing and get the URL for next step.

When I try to to get the URL of the envelope, I receive the following error:

```
errorCode: SHARED_VIEW_USER_LACKS_PERMISSION
message: User lacks shared permission to envelope. Only a user with shared access to the envelope may perform the requested operation.
```

Here is the code I'm using on my PHP application to try to get the URL of the recent created envelope:

```
$envelope = $this->docusignlib->create_document_for_signing($user, $file);
$result = $this->docusignlib->get_url_document($user, $envelope['envelope_id'], $return_url);
```

```
   public function create_document_for_signing($user, $file)
   {
      # Document
      $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([
         'document_base64' =>  base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)),
         'name' => 'Document name',
         'file_extension' => 'pdf',
         'document_id' => '1'
      ]);

      # Sign Here Position
      $signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
         'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2', 'recipient_id' => '1',
         'tab_label' => 'Sign here', 'x_position' => '100', 'y_position' => '720'
      ]);

      # The signer object
      $signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
         'email' => $user->user_email,
         'name' => $user->user_name,
         'recipient_id' => "1",
         'client_user_id' => $user->user_id,
         'tabs' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
            'sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere]
         ])
      ]);

      # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
      $envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
         'email_subject' => "Email subject",
         'documents' => [$document],
         'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
         'status' => "sent"
      ]);

      $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
      $config->setHost($this->api);
      $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $this->accessToken);
      $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
      $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
      return $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($this->accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
   }
```

```
   public function get_url_document($user, $envelopeId, $returnUrl)
   {
      $recipientViewRequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
         'user_name' => $user->user_name,
         'email' => $user->user_email,
         "recipient_id" => "1",
         "client_user_id" => $user->user_id,
         "authentication_method" => "email",
         "return_url" => $returnUrl
      ]);


      $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
      $config->setHost($this->api);
      $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $this->accessToken);
      $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
      $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
      return $envelopeApi->createEnvelopeRecipientSharedView($this->accountId, $envelopeId, $recipientViewRequest);
   }
```

I couldn't find ANYTHING related to this error on the documentation and I checked all the permissions and everything seems ok. I'm using the admin user of my demoaccount. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you obtain your access token? did you use JWT?

Comment: @InbarGazit for now I'm generating manually at https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator

Comment: ok, when you use this URL you had to log into DocuSign Developer Sandbox (demo). that account you use (email/password) should match the envelopeID you used in the API call. It should be an admin account with access to that envelope. Can you also confirm the envelopeID ?

Comment: The envelope is created successfully. I can retrieve the envelopeID from createEnvelope(). So I'm using the envelopeID on the createEnvelopeRecipientSharedView() call. I'm currently using the admin user from my account.

Comment: I mean when you use developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator which user do you use? same one? it must be the admin user for the same account

Comment: Yes. It's the same user. On my admindemo.docusign.com/users I have only the admin user.

Comment: not sure, if you're getting this error - SHARED_VIEW_USER_LACKS_PERMISSION it's about the user and the account. You may want to try a different account and/or a new envelope. I would also ensure that you are making API call to demo.docusign.net URL and not www.docusign.net since you are still in demo/sandbox.

Comment: I feel I'm missing something. Probably related to Consent. I'll revisit the whole documentation to check where I'm getting wrong. As I said, sending a simple email with the link for signing is working. I'll ping you back soon here.

Comment: The Token Generator website you are using should have asked for consent. It is only needed once. This is using Auth Code Grant, not JWT

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info.

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Not yet. I'm going to create another account from scratch and start over next week. I let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

SHARED_VIEW_USER_LACKS_PERMISSION is about the user and the account. You may want to try a different account and/or a new envelope. I would also ensure that you are making API call to demo.docusign.net URL and not www.docusign.net since you are still in demo/sandbox.
The accessToken should match the account and if you're using the token generator, it's the account that you used when token generator prompted you to log in.